# How can I font awesome icon after form field label in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How can I add the following html after a form field label in yii2

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
```

Field code currently

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'title') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => '{label}<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i><div class="col-sm-10">{input}</div><div class="col-sm-10">{error}</div>',
        'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply try this :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->label('Title <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>') ?>
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#label()-detail

PS: or use *vitalik_74* answer to modify all your fields.